# Wordpress Widget Not Saving Instance

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, widgets, widget-text

I have very simple wordpress widget, that has 3 input field. Whenever i submit data, it does not save to database. I have added and deleted the plugin , deactivated and reactivated multiple times, but no luck. Below is my code :-

```
    class price_package extends WP_Widget {

    function  __construct() {
        parent::__construct(
            'price_package',
            'Price Package',
            array(
                'classname' => 'price-package',
                'description' => 'Wordpress Package Page Creator'
            )
        );
        add_action('admin_print_styles', array($this, 'register_admin_styles'));
        add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'register_widget_styles'));
        add_shortcode('package', function($atts, $content = null) {
            $atts = shortcode_atts(
                array(
                    'name' => 'Super Platinum',
                    'content' => 'No description available.'
                ), $atts
            );
            extract($atts);
            include(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__).'/views/package.php');
        });
    }

    function form ($instance) {
        $instance = wp_parse_args(
            (array)$instance,
            array (
                'name' => '',
                'divclass'  => '',
                'paypal' => '',
            )
        );
        include(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__).'/views/admin.php');
    }

    function update($new_instance, $old_instance) {
        $old_instance['name'] = htmlentities($new_instance['name']);
        $old_instance['divclass'] = htmlentities($new_instance['divclass']);
        $old_instance['paypal'] = htmlentities($new_instance['paypal']);
        return $old_instance;
    }

    function widget($args, $instance) {
        extract($args, EXTR_SKIP);
        echo $before_widget;
        include(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__).'/views/widget.php');
        echo $after_widget;
    }

    function register_admin_styles() {
        wp_enqueue_style('price-package', plugins_url('price-package/css/admin.css'));
    }

    function register_widget_styles() {
        wp_enqueue_style('price-package', plugins_url('price-package/css/widget.css'));
    }
}

add_action('widgets_init', create_function('', 'register_widget("price_package");'));
```

Let me know, if i am doing some mistake.

Comment: shouldn't `return $old_instance;` be `return $new_instance;`?

Comment: I also tried changing `$old_instance` to `$new_instance` , But no change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your update function. $old_instance is kind of special variable. The simplest is

```
function update($new_instance, $old_instance) {
    return $new_instance;
}
```

For the safe

```
function update($new_instance, $old_instance) {
        $instance = array();
        $instance['name'] = htmlentities($new_instance['name']);
        $instance['divclass'] = htmlentities($new_instance['divclass']);
        $instance['paypal'] = htmlentities($new_instance['paypal']);
        return $instance;
    }
```

Comment: I did exactly what you have done , but still it is not saving.

Comment: So, it is in the file of this one include(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__).'/views/admin.php');  the input fields in the form must have the name attribute the same as 'name', 'divclass', 'paypal'

Comment: oh my god! i just forgot to use echo. i replaced my code `<?php $this->get_field_id('name'); ?>` to `<?php echo $this->get_field_id('name'); ?>`